# Retrieve stats from Google Analytics for Android App

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have integrated Google Analytics into my Android app. The app is a photo printing app which contains a set of predefined themes that users can choose. However, is it possible to retrieve the stats from Google Analytics (e.g., the top 5 themes selected by user) using some api rather than using the Google Analytics console?

Comment: It might be easier to hard code it. A lot of the time that's how sites/apps do "top 5 things". You can always head over to /r/SampleSize and set up a Google Form to ask people what their top 5 would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for to retrieve the information is the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/?hl=en). Because the Google Analytics API requires all requests to be authenticated and your users are not [authorized](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization) to access your Google Analytics account It is probably best to set up the API call on the server side using a service account here is an example of how to set up a [python application](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) to use a service account to access the API.

But what should your query be?

```
analytics.data().ga().get(
    ids='ga:' + profile_id,
    start_date='30daysAgo',
    end_date='today',
    metrics='ga:totalEvents',
    dimensions='ga:eventLabels').execute()
```

Your application will need a way to access the results of the query from your own servers. You might also want to look into using the [Google Analytics Super Proxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) which solves a similar problem of allowing external users to access the results of an authenticated API request.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event in Google Analytics that would effectively track this. Events have Categories, Actions, labels, and event values. So you can fairly effectively add a theme or anything you wanted as a dynamic value. Then you would be able to search and sort in Google Analytics on the event category and find which Theme was used the most

```
@Override
public void themeSelected(String theme) {
   // May return null if a Tracker has not yet been initialized with a
   // property ID.
   Tracker tracker = Tracker.getInstance(this);

  // that are set and sent with the hit.
  tracker.send(MapBuilder
      .createEvent("Theme",       // Event category (required)
               "Theme Selected",  // Event action (required)
               theme,             // Event label - Can dynamically set this with the theme that was selected so you can search in Google Analytics on it.
               null)              // Event value 
  .build()
  );
}
```

Screenshot showing sorting off of the Event Label. My labels were numbers that users entered. Notice you can see the number of times each one was entered in the TotalEvents Column which should give you the information you were looking for

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics sorting]